Converting triangles to quads
I used the knife to to cut out the windows of a plane cockpit. Now I have triangles that I've been trying to clean up.

I've gotten a few of them but the rest I can't figure out. Could somebody explain a few methods to remove triangles like these?


You could use this topology instead:


I'm sorry to ask you again, I'm not very good with blender could please explain how you got it here?

There was no real magic method unfortunately, I used the knife and dissolved some edges until I got this result
